# For loop in R with many values

Tags: r

I have equations which I would like to test with many different values and find the one solution for those equations. So the idea is to find T_out, and all the other values are known. For this I want to test values from 45 to 30 in 0.001 steps.

```
T_out =326.5 

for (i in seq(45, 30, by = -0.001)){
T_out=T_out-i;
Q_in=0.16*0.8*(316-300.4-T_out-300.4) / (log(316-300.4 / T_out-300.4));
Q_out=0.00762*1512*(316-T_out);
if (Q_in-Q_out==0){
  break
end}
T_out_new=T_out-i;   
}
```

But nothing happens. Do you know what is the mistake?

Comment: Not reproducible: `T_out` is undefined.  But I suspect you're not taking account of numerical inaccuracy.  `Q_in - Q_out` is *most unlikely* to be *exactly* equal to zero.  One option would be to use `if (abs(Q_in-Q_out) < 0.0001)` or some other reasonably small number.  But there are also more efficient ways of finding zeroes of functions....

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I changed the if statement, but still nothing happens... Do you know why this could be?

Comment: Also pay attention to the syntax (R does not require semicolon). the calculation `(log(316-300.4 / T_out-300.4))` may return non numeric values for `T_out < 300.4`, which is never desirable. Finally, remember that the best loop is no loop at all and it is always better to use mathematical solutions. This kind equation might be solved algebrically or using Newton-Raphson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are vectorised function and you should need `for` loop for this.

```
T_out = 326.5 
vals = seq(45, 30, by = -0.001)
T_val = T_out - vals
Q_in = 0.16*0.8*(316-300.4-T_val-300.4) / (log(316-300.4 / T_val-300.4))
Q_out = 0.00762*1512*(316-T_val)
vals[which((Q_in - Q_out) == 0)]
```

However, none of the numbers satisfy the condition and it returns `numeric(0)`. Maybe you need to adjust some values ?